# How to substitute multiple symbols in an expression in sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

Assigning a variable directly does not modify expressions that used the variable retroactively.

```
>>> from sympy import Symbol
>>> x = Symbol('x')
>>> y = Symbol('y')
>>> f = x + y
>>> x = 0

>>> f
x + y
```

Comment: check out: http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/basic_operations.html for `expr.subs(x,val)`

Comment: The question in the title has no actual answer on this page, but it can be found [here](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorials/intro-tutorial/basic_operations.html): *To perform multiple substitutions at once, pass a list of `(old, new)` pairs to `subs`*, example: `expr.subs([(x, 2), (y, 4), (z, 0)])`

Comment: Is exprs.subs( list) faster asymptotically than doing one by one? What exactly happens when you pass the list in?

Comment: It doesn't seem obvious to me: the source code for subs and _subs can be found here https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/core/basic.py

Answer (score 53, accepted):

To substitute several values:

```
>>> from sympy import Symbol
>>> x, y = Symbol('x y')
>>> f = x + y
>>> f.subs({x:10, y: 20})
>>> f
30
```

Comment: Was looking for an answer to this earlier. I understand why my code didn't work but I just needed a quick reference for the syntax to sub the values. Couldn't find anything within my first google search so I thought I would share the answer after I figured it out to hopefully save the next guy sometime. Posting Q&A style is a feature of stackoverflow. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290038/answer-your-own-question-qa-style

Comment: what if f is a matrix of symbols? as in `a = symarray('a', 3)`?

Comment: What is happening when this does not work? Is there a difference between Symbol and sympy.var?

Answer (score 6):

The command `x = Symbol('x')` stores Sympy's `Symbol('x')` into Python's variable `x`. The Sympy expression `f` that you create afterwards does contain `Symbol('x')`, not the Python variable `x`.

When you reassign `x = 0`, the Python variable `x` is set to zero, and is no longer related to `Symbol('x')`. This has no effect on the Sympy expression, which still contains `Symbol('x')`.

This is best explained in this page of the Sympy documentation:
http://docs.sympy.org/latest/gotchas.html#variables

What you want to do is `f.subs(x,0)`, as said in other answers.

Comment: what if f is a matrix of symbols? as in `a = symarray('a', 3)`?

Answer (score 2):

Actually sympy is designed not to substitute values until you really want to substitute them with `subs` (see http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/basic_operations.html)

Try

```
f.subs({x:0})
f.subs(x, 0) # as alternative
```

instead of

```
x = 0
```

Comment: what if f is a matrix of symbols? as in `a = symarray('a', 3)`?