# how to calculate derivative in python using sympy

Tags: python-3.x

I have the function `(x ** 2 - 612)`,
Its derivative is `(2*x)`, in which `sympy`.

However, I would like to assign a value for `x`.

example: `(2*10)`

```
import sympy as sp


x = sp.Symbol('x')

func = (x**2 - 612)
dx = (sp.diff(func,x))

print(dx)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40609184/python-changing-symbol-variable-and-assign-numerical-value/40636225

Comment: Correct, thank you @gmdev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40609184/python-changing-symbol-variable-and-assign-numerical-value/40636225)

```
from sympy import *

x = Symbol('x')
f = (x**2 - 612) 

dx = (diff(f,x)) 
r = dx.subs({x:10})

print(r)
```