# TypeError: can't convert expression to floatv

Tags: python, matrix, odeint

I am trying to access the elements of a matrix to use them as expressions when I call another function that will calculate some differential equations for me. However, in the line that I have

*"dydt = odeint(model,[0,0],t) #(model, initial conditions, t)"*
it returns me the following error:

**"TypeError: can't convert expression to float"**

Does anybody know how to solve that? Thank you very much!
Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from math import *
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from sympy import Symbol

vas= Symbol("vas")
ZL_r= Symbol("ZL_r")
ias= Symbol("ias")
iar_r= Symbol("iar_r")
global A
A = np.array([[1.58730158730159*iar_r*(ZL_r + 1.0) - 1.74603174603175*ias + 1.74603174603175*vas],
         [-1.74603174603175*iar_r*(ZL_r + 1.0) + 1.58730158730159*ias - 1.58730158730159*vas]])

def model(y, t):

    ias = y[0]
    iar_r = y[1]

    alpha = 480.0 / 208
    vas = (480.0/sqrt(3))*sqrt(2)*cos(377*t-30*3.14/180)
    ZL_r = 10*alpha**2

    dydt = [[], []]
    dydt[0] = A[0][0]
    dydt[1] = A[1][0]

    return dydt

t = np.linspace(0,19,50000)
dydt = odeint(model,[0,0],t) #(model, initial conditions, t)

plt.plot(dydt[:, 0])
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to substitute multiple symbols in an expression in sympy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32930284/how-to-substitute-multiple-symbols-in-an-expression-in-sympy)

Comment: It is different. My problem is happening when I call the matrix elements to use it as an expression

Comment: You've included a lot of code, is there any way to narrow down the problem. Is there a specific function that's throwing the error?

Comment: @MatAff The error is happening here: dydt[0] = p_I_matrix[0][0] . When I call the p_I_matrix element, dydt[0] has the format "sympy.core.add.Add". But the content of p_I_matrix[0][0] is an expression:

"1.0752688172043*iar_r*(ZL1_r + 1.0) - 2.25806451612903*ias - 0.53763440860215*ibr_r*(ZL2_r + 1.0) - 0.53763440860215*ibs - 0.53763440860215*icr_r*(ZL3_r + 1.0) - 0.537634408602149*ics + 2.25806451612903*vas + 0.53763440860215*vbs + 0.537634408602149*vcs"

Comment: So when the ODEINT function try to work with the dydt[0], it returns the error, because I think dydt[0] should be in float format. If I creat a new variable, for example a and paste the expression on it, and then say that dydt[0] = a it works

Comment: If you mean `a = "2.3+Zl+vas+3.43"`, then no, it will not do what you expect. If you mean `a = eval("2.3+Zl+vas+3.43")` then yes, you are basically doing the sympy variable substitution using python's `eval` instead. And yes the fundamental problem is `dydt[0]` not being a float.

Comment: I assume you have a good reason to use sympy, but if this is the only thing you are using it for, then dropping it in favor of a simple function taking the `Lls` etc. parameters and returning the model function would be much easier to write and better performing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `dydt` which you construct still contains sympy expressions with free symbols. I suppose your intention with the previous assignments in the function is to set the symbols in all sympy expressions using them. However assignment in Python is name binding. You are actually just binding the calculated values to the names that (in the other function by the way) were bound to the sympy symbols.

You need to actually substitute the values into the sympy expression. Quick and dirty:

```
dydt = [x[0].subs(locals()) for x in p_I_matrix]
```

Replace `locals()` by a dictionary constructed from all the assignments you made earlier to make this cleaner.

Here is the `model` function with the quick solution:

```
def model(y, t):

    ias = y[0]
    ibs = y[1]
    ics = y[2]
    iar_r = y[3]
    ibr_r = y[4]
    icr_r = y[5]

    alpha = 480.0 / 208

    vas = (480.0/m.sqrt(3))*m.sqrt(2)*m.cos(377*t-30*m.pi/180)
    vbs = (480.0/m.sqrt(3))*m.sqrt(2)*m.cos(377*t-150*m.pi/180)
    vcs = (480.0/m.sqrt(3))*m.sqrt(2)*m.cos(377*t-270*m.pi/180)

    ZL1_r = 10.0 * alpha ** 2
    ZL2_r = 10.0 * alpha ** 2
    ZL3_r = 10.0 * alpha ** 2

    return [x[0].subs(locals()) for x in p_I_matrix]
```

This works as intended and will substitute all variables local to the function scope (the ones assigned to in the function) if they match the sympy symbol names inside the expressions. The list comprehension simplifies the code a lot (and should actually also be used for all the numbered variables).

One might say that using `locals()` in this way is not very clean, because it might substitute any symbol in the sympy expression if there happens to be an unrelated use of a local variable with the same name. Therefore it is better to explicitly give a list of symbols to substitute:

```
def model(y, t):

    ias = y[0]
    ibs = y[1]
    ics = y[2]
    iar_r = y[3]
    ibr_r = y[4]
    icr_r = y[5]

    alpha = 480.0 / 208

    vas = (480.0/m.sqrt(3))*m.sqrt(2)*m.cos(377*t-30*m.pi/180)
    vbs = (480.0/m.sqrt(3))*m.sqrt(2)*m.cos(377*t-150*m.pi/180)
    vcs = (480.0/m.sqrt(3))*m.sqrt(2)*m.cos(377*t-270*m.pi/180)

    ZL1_r = 10.0 * alpha ** 2
    ZL2_r = 10.0 * alpha ** 2
    ZL3_r = 10.0 * alpha ** 2

    subs_dict = {
        'ias': ias,
        'ibs': ibs,
        'ics': ics,
        'iar_r': iar_r,
        'ibr_r': ibr_r,
        'icr_r': icr_r,
        'vas': vas,
        'vbs': vbs,
        'vcs': vcs,
        'ZL1_r': ZL1_r,
        'ZL2_r': ZL2_r,
        'ZL3_r': ZL3_r
    }

    return [x[0].subs(subs_dict) for x in p_I_matrix]
```

A version without sympy, because it is much more efficient:

```
def make_model(Lls=0.3,Lms=3.0,Llr_r=0.3,rp=1.0,rs=1.0):        

    alpha = 480.0 / 208

    L = np.array([[Lls+Lms, -0.5*Lms, -0.5*Lms, Lms, -0.5*Lms, -0.5*Lms],
              [-0.5*Lms, Lls+Lms, -0.5*Lms, -0.5*Lms, Lms, -0.5*Lms],
              [-0.5*Lms, -0.5*Lms, Lls+Lms, -0.5*Lms, -0.5*Lms, Lms],
              [Lms, -0.5*Lms, -0.5*Lms, Llr_r+Lms, -0.5*Lms, -0.5*Lms],
              [-0.5*Lms, Lms, -0.5*Lms, -0.5*Lms, Llr_r+Lms, -0.5*Lms],
              [-0.5*Lms, -0.5*Lms, Lms, -0.5*Lms, -0.5*Lms, Llr_r+Lms]])

    def model(y, t):

        ias = y[0]
        ibs = y[1]
        ics = y[2]
        iar_r = y[3]
        ibr_r = y[4]
        icr_r = y[5]

        vas = (480.0/m.sqrt(3))*m.sqrt(2)*m.cos(377*t-30*m.pi/180)
        vbs = (480.0/m.sqrt(3))*m.sqrt(2)*m.cos(377*t-150*m.pi/180)
        vcs = (480.0/m.sqrt(3))*m.sqrt(2)*m.cos(377*t-270*m.pi/180)

        ZL1_r = 10.0 * alpha ** 2
        ZL2_r = 10.0 * alpha ** 2
        ZL3_r = 10.0 * alpha ** 2

        r = np.array([[rp, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, rp, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, rp, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, rs+ZL1_r, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, rs+ZL2_r, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, rs+ZL3_r]])

        v = np.array([[vas],
              [vbs],
              [vcs],
              [0],
              [0],
              [0]])

        i = np.array([[ias],
              [ibs],
              [ics],
              [iar_r],
              [ibr_r],
              [icr_r]])

        inverse_L = np.linalg.inv(L)
        p_I_matrix = np.dot(inverse_L,(v - np.dot(r,i)))
        return [x[0] for x in p_I_matrix]

    return model

t = np.linspace(139.5,140,1000000)
dydt = odeint(make_model(),[0,0,0,0,0,0],t) #(model, initial conditions, t)
```

There is also room for improvement in this model function, but it should be much faster and is easier to write/read.

Comment: Sorry @eukaryota, I don't get it. I have 5 dydt's     dydt[0] = eval(str(p_I_matrix[0][0]))
    dydt[1] = eval(str(p_I_matrix[1][0]))
    dydt[2] = eval(str(p_I_matrix[2][0]))
    dydt[3] = eval(str(p_I_matrix[3][0]))
    dydt[4] = eval(str(p_I_matrix[4][0]))
    dydt[5] = eval(str(p_I_matrix[5][0])) locals() would be a dictionary with all my symbols (ZL1_r, vas, etc)?  Could you please show me an example?

Comment: I used a list comprehension to create all of them at once. Where does `eval(str(` suddenly come from now? Just replace your lines starting with `dydt` with the single line I gave and see whether it works. If not let me know. If it is not clear what the syntax means, look up list comprehensions, dictionaries, `locals()` and the possible duplicate I linked earlier.

Comment: it returned an error @eukaryota  "unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'tuple' and 'int'". I created the dictionary my_dict = dict({vas: '(480.0/m.sqrt(3))*m.sqrt(2)*m.cos(377*t-30*m.pi/180)', vbs: '(480.0/m.sqrt(3))*m.sqrt(2)*m.cos(377*t-150*m.pi/180)', vcs: '(480.0/m.sqrt(3))*m.sqrt(2)*m.cos(377*t-270*m.pi/180)', ZL1_r: '10.0 * alpha ** 2', ZL2_r: '10.0 * alpha ** 2', ZL3_r: '10.0 * alpha ** 2', alpha: '480.0/208'}) is that correct?

Comment: Yeah, that dictionary is wrong. Did you try the exact line I gave, did that work? If so you can clean it up with the dictionary afterwards. The dict should have the form `my_dict = {'vas': (480.0/m.sqrt(3))*m.sqrt(2)*m.cos(377*t-30*m.pi/180), ...}'`.

Comment: ... or if you keep the assignments made in the current code, simply `my_dict = {'vas': vas, ...}`

Comment: I created the dictionary     my_dict = {'vas': (480.0/m.sqrt(3))*m.sqrt(2)*m.cos(377*t-30*m.pi/180),
                    'vbs': (480.0/m.sqrt(3))*m.sqrt(2)*m.cos(377*t-150*m.pi/180),
                    'vcs': (480.0/m.sqrt(3))*m.sqrt(2)*m.cos(377*t-270*m.pi/180),
                    'ZL1_r': 10.0 * alpha ** 2,
                    'ZL2_r': 10.0 * alpha ** 2,
                    'ZL3_r': 10.0 * alpha ** 2,
                    'alpha': 480.0/208}

Comment: and then used what you suggested (dydt = [x[0].subs(my_dict()) for x in p_I_matrix]) but it keeps giving me the error "unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'tuple' and 'int'".

Comment: Would you mind post the full code @eukaryota? Sorry, I am struggling with that

Comment: @CharlesWagner See edit. Also try to use lists and list comprehension whenever you have multiple related variables like `vas/vbs/vcs`. It'll save a lot of copy-pasting and typo/error potential.

Comment: Thank you @eukaryota but when I run the code now it just keeps loading and it never plots the graphic..

Comment: @CharlesWagner Because you are sampling `1000000` points and this sympy method is extremely inefficient (My completely unverified guess would be about a factor 100 slower than a simple function doing the same). Reduce the number of sampling points.

Comment: it loaded after a while but the answer was not correct

Comment: @CharlesWagner Well I can't tell you where your math is wrong.

Comment: The math is not wrong, because if I declare dydt[0] with the expression that is inside of p_I_matrix[0][0] instead of making what you suggested, for example, the code shows me the right answer. But thank you