# Substitute numerical constants with symbols in sympy

Tags: sympy

I have a question similar to this one: [How to substitute multiple symbols in an expression in sympy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32930284/how-to-substitute-multiple-symbols-in-an-expression-in-sympy) but in reverse.

I have a `sympy` expression with numerical values and symbols alike. I would like to substitute all numerical values with symbolic constants. I appreciate that such query is uncommon for `sympy`. What can I try next?

For example, I have:

`-0.5967695*sin(0.15280747*x0 + 0.89256966) + 0.5967695*sin(sin(0.004289882*x0 - 1.5390939))` and would like to replace all numbers with `a`, `b`, `c` etc. ideally in a batch type of way.

The goal is to then apply trig identities to simplify the expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is already such a function. If there is not, it's quite easy to build one. For example:

```py
import string

def num2symbols(expr):
    # wild symbol to select all numbers
    w = Wild("w", properties=[lambda t: isinstance(t, Number)])
    # extract the numbers from the expression
    n = expr.find(w)
    # get a lowercase alphabet
    alphabet = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
    # create a symbol for each number
    s = symbols(" ".join(alphabet[:len(n)]))
    # create a dictionary mapping a number to a symbol
    d = {k: v for k, v in zip(n, s)}
    return d, expr.subs(d)

x0 = symbols("x0")
expr = -0.5967695*sin(0.15280747*x0 + 0.89256966) + 0.5967695*sin(sin(0.004289882*x0 - 1.5390939))
d, new_expr = num2symbols(expr)
print(new_expr)
# out: b*sin(c + d*x0) - b*sin(sin(a + f*x0))
print(d):
# {-1.53909390000000: a, -0.596769500000000: b, 0.892569660000000: c, 0.152807470000000: d, 0.596769500000000: e, 0.00428988200000000: f}
```

Comment: Hi @Davide_sd thank you for your answer. I wanted to edit the function but the queue is full. It should be sympy.Wild and sympy.Number for it to work correctly. If you or anyone else does that, I shall accept the answer.

Comment: I just had a closer look, your solution even finds unique numbers, all the better! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I feel like `dict.setdefault` was made for this purpose in Python :-)

```
>>> c = numbered_symbols('c',cls=Dummy)
>>> d = {}
>>> econ = expr.replace(lambda x:x.is_Float, lambda x: sign(x)*d.setdefault(abs(x),next(c)))
>>> undo = {v:k for k,v in d.items()}
```

Do what you want with `econ` and when done (after saving results to econ)

```
>>> econ.xreplace(undo) == expr
True
```

(But if you change econ the exact equivalence may no longer hold.) This uses `abs` to store symbols so if the expression has constants that differ by a sign they will appear in `econ` with `+/-ci` instead of `ci` and `cj`.