# I am looking for a way to replace a variable "x" which is an unknown in an equation with another variable "x_v" which is known

Tags: python, sympy

```
from sympy import *
import numpy as np

x = symbols('x')
y = sin(0.5*x)
vx = -15
x_v = 2*np.pi

slope = diff(y)
print(slope)

s = 0.5*cos(0.5*x_v)
theta = atan(s)
vy = tan(theta) * vx

print(vy)
```

I have this bit of code. `y` is my function, `vx` is the velocity of a particle moving along the function in the `vx` direction, `x_v` is the position of the particle at a given time. I need to solve for `vy`, the velocity of the position at position `x_v`.

I am attempting to solve for `vy` which is the velocity of the particle in the `y` direction. My method was to first find the slope of the function by differentiating `y` and then inputting my value for `x_v` into the slope equation. My current method is to print the slope formula and then re-write it, replacing the unknown `x` variable with my given `x_v` variable. Is there a way I can call the slope function and just have python replace the unknown `x` variable with my given `x_v` variable so I have a general method of solving this problem when the function and other values change?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to substitute multiple symbols in an expression in sympy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32930284/how-to-substitute-multiple-symbols-in-an-expression-in-sympy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `expression.subs` [method](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-sympy-subs-method-2/) or in the [basic operation doc](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorials/intro-tutorial/basic_operations.html#substitution).
Try using:

```
s = slope.subs(x,x_v)
```

Comment: Or `s = lambda x_v: slope.subs(x, x_v)` so now you can call it like `s(1)` to get the slope at `x=1`.